# Binary numbers addition

Tags: binary, computer-science, hardware, binaryfiles, binary-data

I have just started doing some binary number exercices to prepare for a class that i will start next month and i got the hang of all the conversion from decimal to binary and viceverca But now with the two letters 'a ' ' b' in this exercise i am not sure how can i apply that knowledge to add the bits with the following exercise

Given two Binary numbers a = (a7a6 ... a0) and b = (b7b6 ... b0).There is a clculator  that can add 4-bit binary numbers.How many bits will be used to represent the result of a 4-bit addition? Why?

We would like to use our calculator to calculate a + b. For this we can put as many as eight bits (4 bits of the first and 4 bits of the second number) of our choice in the calculator and continue to use the result bit by bit

- How many additions does our calculator have to carry out for the addition of a and b at most? How many bits is the result maximum long?
- How many additions does the calculator have to perform at least For the result to be correct for all possible inputs a and b?

Answer (score 0):

The number of bits needed to represent a 4-bit binary addition is 5.  This is because there could be a carry-over bit that pushes the result to 5 bits.

For example 1111 + 0010 = 10010.

This can be done the same way as adding decimal numbers. From right to left just add the numbers of the same significance. If the two bits are 1+1, the result is 10 so that place becomes a zero and the 1 carries over to the next pair of bits, just like decimal addition.

With regard to the min/max number of step, these seems more like an algorithm specific question.  Look up some different binary addition algorithms, like ripple-carry for instance, and it should give you a better idea of what is meant by the question.